# Gradle error "finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem with my project. I got error when I ran my project.

> finished with non-zero exit value 2

**App** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile project(':libraryMugen')
}
```

**libraryMugen** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

**edited :**

It seems the error occurs when **App** and **libraryMugen** contain the same dependencies:

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: my questions is edited, please check again sir, thanks :)

Comment: try to post the stacktrace of your gradle error

Comment: ``Error:Execution failed for task ':kDG:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2``

Answer (score 0):

Check that your file path's are <= 260 characters. I use that same library and get dinged for it constantly.

Comment: How to check it ? Please

Comment: Go ahead and try to run your app until it hits the error, and give us like the first 10 rows above the error itself. That will show some file's and their paths that are causing trouble.